# How to create a javascript functions that accept parameters or type and methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a novice in javascript programming and just want to learn more about functions and fascinated with javascript libraries like jquery and I am intrigued by how was it made and I also noticed that all pre-functions like ajax accept parameters,type or methods like below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : 'test.php',
    data : XXX   
})
```

My question is how does it process this parameter? or how to construct a similar function like above.

Comment: `var $ = {ajax: function(params) { for (var p in params) { console.log(p, params[p]) } } }`

Comment: In the example `$.ajax` is only called with one parameter which is an object. Notice the `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a "normal" function where the parameter you pass is a object. So you can build a function like so:

```js
var myFunction = function(options) {
    console.log(options.one);
    console.log(options.two);
};


var someObject = {
    one: 'one',
    two: 'two'
};

myFunction(someObject);

// which is the same as 

myFunction({one: 'blubb', two: 'blubb two'});
```

So now the problem might be that someone uses the function without setting the options so you can set default if no options are set like so

```js
var myFunction = function(options) {
    var options = options || {};
        options.one = options.one || 'hello';
        options.two = options.two || 'world';
    console.log(options.one);
    console.log(options.two);
};

myFunction();
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, I was also wondering what if an option was not set. cheers!

Answer (score 3):

It's just an object stored in the variable `$` with the property `ajax`, which is a function, which takes an `object` as a parameter:

```js
    var $ = {
        ajax: function(params) {
            console.log(params.type, params.url, params.data);
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : 'test.php',
        data : { test: 'data' }   
    })
```